# How to configure storage card for the Windows Mobile emulator by source code?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.5

How can I programmatically configure a storage card for the Windows Mobile emulator?

I'm automating my tests. I can make a cradle and connect. Now I just need to configure the storage card.

Comment: You need to describe more. Where do you want that program to run? On the emulator?

Comment: [Article MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb936678.aspx) This link tells you how to make the cradle and connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use SetConfiguration method from IDeviceEmulatorManagerVMID interface. These articles explain in more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531176(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531167(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531162(v=vs.90).aspx